# How to integrate js anim in vuejs

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have 2 files for an animation: `Index.html` and `lazy-line-painter-1.9.6.min.js`

I want to integrate this animation to my vuejs code.

I tried to put everything in the right place in my vuejs code (style, script, template) but I don't really know how to do it properly. Thanks

```
!function(t,e){"object"==typeof exports&&"object"==typeof module?module.exports=e():"function"==typeof define&&define.amd?define("lazy-line-painter",[],e):"object"==typeof exports?exports["lazy-line-painter"]=e():t["lazy-line-painter"]=e()}(window,function(){return function(t){var e={};function i(n){if(e[n])return e[n].exports;var s=e[n]={i:n,l:!1,exports:{}};return t[n].call(s.exports,s,s.exports,i),s.l=!0,s.exports}return i.m=t,i.c=e,i.d=function(t,e,n){i.o(t,e)||Object.defineProperty(t,e,{enumerable:!0,get:n})},i.r=function(t){"undefined"!=typeof Symbol&&Symbol.toStringTag&&Object.defineProperty(t,Symbol.toStringTag,{value:"Module"}),Object.defineProperty(t,"__esModule",{value:!0})},i.t=function(t,e){if(1&e&&(t=i(t)),8&e)return t;if(4&e&&"object"==typeof t&&t&&t.__esModule)return t;var n=Object.create(null);if(i.r(n),Object.defineProperty(n,"default",{enumerable:!0,value:t}),2&e&&"string"!=typeof t)for(var s in t)i.d(n,s,function(e){return t[e]}.bind(null,s));return n},i.n=function(t){var e=t&&t.__esModule?function(){return t.default}:function(){return t};return i.d(e,"a",e),e},i.o=function(t,e){return Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(t,e)},i.p="",i(i.s=2)}([function(t,e,i){"use strict";Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0}),e.default=void 0;var n={easeLinear:function(t){return t},easeInQuad:function(t){return t*t},easeOutQuad:function(t){return t*(2-t)},easeInOutQuad:function(t){return(t*=2)<1?.5*t*t:-.5*(--t*(t-2)-1)},easeInCubic:function(t){return t*t*t},easeOutCubic:function(t){return--t*t*t+1},easeInOutCubic:function(t){return(t*=2)<1?.5*t*t*t:.5*((t-=2)*t*t+2)},easeInQuart:function(t){return t*t*t*t},easeOutQuart:function(t){return 1- --t*t*t*t},easeInOutQuart:function(t){return(t*=2)<1?.5*t*t*t*t:-.5*((t-=2)*t*t*t-2)},easeInQuint:function(t){return t*t*t*t*t},easeOutQuint:function(t){return--t*t*t*t*t+1},easeInOutQuint:function(t){return(t*=2)<1?.5*t*t*t*t*t:.5*((t-=2)*t*t*t*t+2)},easeInSine:function(t){return 1-Math.cos(t*Math.PI/2)},easeOutSine:function(t){return Math.sin(t*Math.PI/2)},easeInOutSine:function(t){return.5*(1-Math.cos(Math.PI*t))},easeInExpo:function(t){return 0===t?0:Math.pow(1024,t-1)},easeOutExpo:function(t){return 1===t?t:1-Math.pow(2,-10*t)},easeInOutExpo:function(t){return 0===t?0:1===t?1:(t*=2)<1?.5*Math.pow(1024,t-1):.5*(2-Math.pow(2,-10*(t-1)))},easeInCirc:function(t){return 1-Math.sqrt(1-t*t)},easeOutCirc:function(t){return Math.sqrt(1- --t*t)},easeInOutCirc:function(t){return(t*=2)<1?-.5*(Math.sqrt(1-t*t)-1):.5*(Math.sqrt(1-(t-=2)*t)+1)},easeInBounce:function(t){return 1-this.easeOutBounce(1-t)},easeOutBounce:function(t){return t<1/2.75?7.5625*t*t:t<2/2.75?7.5625*(t-=1.5/2.75)*t+.75:t<2.5/2.75?7.5625*(t-=2.25/2.75)*t+.9375:7.5625*(t-=2.625/2.75)*t+.984375},easeInOutBounce:function(t){return t<.5?.5*this.easeInBounce(2*t):.5*this.easeOutBounce(2*t-1)+.5}};e.default=n,t.exports=e.default},function(t,e,i){"use strict";Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0}),e.default=void 0;var n={on:function(t,e){this._eventEmitterCallbacks=this._eventEmitterCallbacks||{},this._eventEmitterCallbacks[t]=this._eventEmitterCallbacks[t]||[],this._eventEmitterCallbacks[t].push(e)}};n.addListener=n.on,n.off=function(t,e){if(this._eventEmitterCallbacks=this._eventEmitterCallbacks||{},t in this._eventEmitterCallbacks){var i=this._eventEmitterCallbacks[t].indexOf(e);i<0||this._eventEmitterCallbacks[t].splice(i,1)}},n.removeListener=n.off,n.emit=function(t,e){if(this._eventEmitterCallbacks=this._eventEmitterCallbacks||{},t in this._eventEmitterCallbacks){var i=!0,n=!1,s=void 0;try{for(var r,a=this._eventEmitterCallbacks[t][Symbol.iterator]();!(i=(r=a.next()).done);i=!0){var o=r.value;if("function"!=typeof o)return;o(e)}}catch(t){n=!0,s=t}finally{try{i||null==a.return||a.return()}finally{if(n)throw s}}}},n.trigger=n.emit;var s=n;e.default=s,t.exports=e.default},function(t,e,i){"use strict";Object.defineProperty(e,"__esModule",{value:!0}),e.default=void 0;var n=r(i(1)),s=r(i(0));function r(t){return t&&t.__esModule?t:{default:t}}function a(t,e){for(var i=0;i<e.length;i++){var n=e[i];n.enumerable=n.enumerable||!1,n.configurable=!0,"value"in n&&(n.writable=!0),Object.defineProperty(t,n.key,n)}}var o=function(){function t(e,i){var s=this;!function(t,e){if(!(t instanceof e))throw new TypeError("Cannot call a class as a function")}(this,t),function(t,e,i){e in t?Object.defineProperty(t,e,{value:i,enumerable:!0,configurable:!0,writable:!0}):t[e]=i}(this,"_onVisibilityChange",function(){document.hidden?s.pause():s.resume()}),this.el=e,this.el.classList.add("lazy-line-painter"),this.config=Object.assign({strokeWidth:null,strokeDash:null,strokeColor:null,strokeOverColor:null,strokeCap:null,strokeJoin:null,strokeOpacity:null,delay:0,ease:null,drawSequential:!1,speedMultiplier:1,reverse:!1,paused:!1,progress:0,repeat:0,longestDuration:0,log:!0,offset:this.el.getBoundingClientRect()},i,{}),Object.assign(this,n.default,{}),this.__raf=null,this.__paths=[],this._generatePaths(),this._parseDataAttrs(),this._updateDuration(),this._setupPaths(),document.addEventListener("visibilitychange",this._onVisibilityChange)}return function(t,e,i){e&&a(t.prototype,e),i&&a(t,i)}(t,[{key:"_generatePaths",value:function(){var t;t=Boolean(this.el.dataset.llpComposed)?this.el.querySelectorAll("[data-llp-id]"):this._uncomposed();for(var e=0;e<t.length;e++){var i={el:t[e]};this.__paths.push(i)}}},{key:"_uncomposed",value:function(){var t,e=this.el.querySelectorAll("path, polygon, circle, ellipse, polyline, line, rect");for(t=0;t<e.length;t++){var i=this.el.id.replace(/ /g,"");i=(i=i.replace(".","")).replace("-",""),e[t].dataset.llpId=i+"-"+t,e[t].dataset.llpDuration||(e[t].dataset.llpDuration=1e3),e[t].dataset.llpDuration||(e[t].dataset.llpDelay=0)}return this.config.log&&console.log("This lazy line is uncomposed! Visit http://lazylinepainter.info to compose your masterpiece!"),e}},{key:"paint",value:function(t){Object.assign(this.config,t),this._updateDuration(),this.erase(),this._paint(),this.emit("start")}},{key:"pause",value:function(){this.config&&(this.config.paused=!0),cancelAnimationFrame(this.__raf),this.emit("pause")}},{key:"resume",value:function(){var t=this;this.config&&this.config.paused&&(requestAnimationFrame(function(){t.adjustStartTime()}),this.config.paused=!1,this.emit("resume"))}},{key:"erase",value:function(){this.config.startTime=null,this.config.elapsedTime=null,cancelAnimationFrame(this.__raf),this.config.onStrokeCompleteDone=!1,this.config.paused=!1;for(var t=0;t<this.__paths.length;t++){var e=this.__paths[t];e.el.style.strokeDashoffset=e.length,e.onStrokeCompleteDone=!1,e.onStrokeStartDone=!1}this.emit("erase")}},{key:"destroy",value:function(){this.config=null,this.el.remove(),this.el=null}},{key:"set",value:function(t,e){switch(t){case"progress":this._setProgress(e);break;case"delay":this._setDelay(e);break;case"reverse":this._setReverse(e);break;case"ease":this._setEase(e);break;case"repeat":this._setRepeat(e);break;default:this.config.log&&console.log("property "+t+" can not be set")}}},{key:"_setRepeat",value:function(t){this.config.repeat=t}},{key:"_setEase",value:function(t){this.config.ease=t}},{key:"_setProgress",value:function(t){this.pause(),this.config.progress=this._getProgress(t,this.config.ease),this._updatePaths(),this.config.elapsedTime=this.config.progress*this.config.totalDuration}},{key:"_setDelay",value:function(t){this.config.delay=t,this._updateDuration()}},{key:"_setReverse",value:function(t){this.config.reverse=t,this._updateDuration()}},{key:"_updateDuration",value:function(){var t=this._getTotalDuration(),e=this._getLongestDuration();this.config.totalDuration=this.config.drawSequential?t:e,this.config.totalDuration+=this.config.delay,this._calcPathDurations()}},{key:"_calcPathDurations",value:function(){for(var t=0;t<this.__paths.length;t++){var e=this.__paths[t],i=void 0;e.progress=0,i=this.config.reverse?this.config.drawSequential?0:this.config.totalDuration-(e.delay+e.duration):this.config.drawSequential?0:this.config.delay+e.delay,e.startTime=i,e.startProgress=e.startTime/this.config.totalDuration,e.durationProgress=e.duration/this.config.totalDuration}}},{key:"get",value:function(){return this.config}},{key:"resize",value:function(){this.config.offset=this.el.getBoundingClientRect();for(var t=0;t<this.__paths.length;t++){var e=this.__paths[t];e.el.getBoundingClientRect(),e.positions=this._getPathPoints(e.el,e.length),this._updatePosition(e)}}},{key:"_parseDataAttrs",value:function(){for(var t=0;t<this.__paths.length;t++){var e=this.__paths[t];e.id=e.el.dataset.llpId,e.delay=Number(e.el.dataset.llpDelay)||0,e.duration=Number(e.el.dataset.llpDuration)||0,e.reverse=Boolean(e.el.dataset.llpReverse)||!1,e.ease=Number(e.el.dataset.llpEase)||null,e.strokeDash=e.el.dataset.llpStrokeDash||null,e.delay*=this.config.speedMultiplier,e.duration*=this.config.speedMultiplier,this._setStyleAttrs(e)}}},{key:"_setStyleAttrs",value:function(t){t.strokeColor=t.el.dataset.llpStrokeColor||this.config.strokeColor,t.strokeColor&&(t.el.style.stroke=t.strokeColor),t.strokeOpacity=t.el.dataset.llpStrokeOpacity||this.config.strokeOpacity,t.strokeOpacity&&(t.el.style.strokeOpacity=t.strokeOpacity),t.strokeWidth=t.el.dataset.llpStrokeWidth||this.config.strokeWidth,t.strokeWidth&&(t.el.style.strokeWidth=t.strokeWidth),t.strokeCap=t.el.dataset.llpStrokeCap||this.config.strokeCap,t.strokeCap&&(t.el.style.strokeLinecap=t.strokeCap),t.strokeJoin=t.el.dataset.llpStrokeJoin||this.config.strokeJoin,t.strokeJoin&&(t.el.style.strokeLinejoin=t.strokeJoin)}},{key:"_setupPaths",value:function(){for(var t=0;t<this.__paths.length;t++){var e=this.__paths[t];e.index=t,e.length=this._getPathLength(e.el),e.positions=this._getPathPoints(e.el,e.length),e.el.style.strokeDasharray=this._getStrokeDashArray(e,e.length),e.el.style.strokeDashoffset=e.length,e.onStrokeStartDone=!1,e.onStrokeCompleteDone=!1}}},{key:"adjustStartTime",value:function(){var t=this,e=performance.now();this.config.startTime=e-this.config.elapsedTime,requestAnimationFrame(function(){t._paint()})}},{key:"_paint",value:function(){var t=this;if(this.config){this.config.startTime||(this.config.startTime=performance.now()),this.emit("update");var e=performance.now();this.config.elapsedTime=e-this.config.startTime,this.config.linearProgress=this.config.elapsedTime/this.config.totalDuration,this.config.progress=this._getProgress(this.config.linearProgress,this.config.ease),this._updatePaths(),this.config.linearProgress>=0&&this.config.linearProgress<=1?this.__raf=requestAnimationFrame(function(){t._paint()}):this.config.repeat>0?(this.config.repeat--,this.paint()):-1===this.config.repeat?this.paint():this.emit("complete")}}},{key:"_updatePaths",value:function(){for(var t=0;t<this.__paths.length;t++){var e=this.__paths[t],i=this._getElapsedProgress(e);e.progress=this._getProgress(i,e.ease),this._setLine(e),this._updatePosition(e),this._updateStrokeCallbacks(e)}}},{key:"_getElapsedProgress",value:function(t){var e;return this.config.progress>=t.startProgress&&this.config.progress<=t.startProgress+t.durationProgress?e=(this.config.progress-t.startProgress)/t.durationProgress:this.config.progress>=t.startProgress+t.durationProgress?e=1:this.config.progress<=t.startProgress&&(e=0),e}},{key:"_getProgress",value:function(t,e){var i=t;return e&&(i=s.default[e](t)),i}},{key:"_setLine",value:function(t){var e=t.el,i=t.progress*t.length;t.reverse?e.style.strokeDashoffset=-t.length+i:this.config.reverse?e.style.strokeDashoffset=-t.length+i:e.style.strokeDashoffset=t.length-i}},{key:"_updateStrokeCallbacks",value:function(t){1===t.progress?t.onStrokeCompleteDone||(t.onStrokeCompleteDone=!0,this.emit("complete:"+t.id,t),this.emit("complete:all",t)):t.progress>1e-5&&(t.onStrokeStartDone||(this.emit("start:"+t.id,t),this.emit("start:all",t),t.onStrokeStartDone=!0),this.emit("update:"+t.id,t),this.emit("update:all",t))}},{key:"_updatePosition",value:function(t){var e=Math.round(t.progress*(t.length-1)),i=t.positions[e];i&&(t.position={x:this.config.offset.left+i.x,y:this.config.offset.top+i.y})}},{key:"_getTotalDuration",value:function(){for(var t=0,e=this.__paths,i=0;i<e.length;i++){var n=e[i].delay||0;t+=e[i].duration+n}return t}},{key:"_getLongestDuration",value:function(){for(var t=0,e=this.__paths,i=0;i<e.length;i++){var n=e[i].delay+e[i].duration;n>t&&(t=n)}return t}},{key:"_getPathLength",value:function(t){return this._getTotalLength(t)}},{key:"_getDistance",value:function(t,e){return Math.sqrt(Math.pow(e.x-t.x,2)+Math.pow(e.y-t.y,2))}},{key:"_getCircleLength",value:function(t){return 2*Math.PI*t.getAttribute("r")}},{key:"_getEllipseLength",value:function(t){var e=parseInt(t.getAttribute("rx"),1),i=parseInt(t.getAttribute("ry"),1),n=Math.pow(e-i,2)/Math.pow(e+i,2);return Math.PI*(e+i)*(1+3*n/Math.sqrt(4-3*n))}},{key:"_getRectLength",value:function(t){return 2*t.getAttribute("width")+2*t.getAttribute("height")}},{key:"_getLineLength",value:function(t){return this._getDistance({x:t.getAttribute("x1"),y:t.getAttribute("y1")},{x:t.getAttribute("x2"),y:t.getAttribute("y2")})}},{key:"_getPolylineLength",value:function(t){for(var e,i=t.points,n=0,s=0;s<i.numberOfItems;s++){var r=i.getItem(s);s>0&&(n+=this._getDistance(e,r)),e=r}return n}},{key:"_getPolygonLength",value:function(t){var e=t.points;return this._getPolylineLength(t)+this._getDistance(e.getItem(e.numberOfItems-1),e.getItem(0))}},{key:"_getTotalLength",value:function(t){var e;switch(t.tagName.toLowerCase()){case"circle":e=this._getCircleLength(t);break;case"rect":e=this._getRectLength(t);break;case"line":e=this._getLineLength(t);break;case"polyline":e=this._getPolylineLength(t);break;case"polygon":e=this._getPolygonLength(t);break;default:e=t.getTotalLength()}return e}},{key:"_getPathPoints",value:function(t,e){for(var i=[],n=0;n<e;n++){var s=t.getPointAtLength(n);i.push({x:s.x,y:s.y})}return i}},{key:"_getStrokeDashArray",value:function(t,e){return t.strokeDash?this._getStrokeDashString(t.strokeDash,e):this.config.strokeDash?this._getStrokeDashString(this.config.strokeDash,e):e+" "+e}},{key:"_getStrokeDashString",value:function(t,e){for(var i,n,s="",r=t.split(","),a=0,o=r.length-1;o>=0;o--)a+=Number(r[o]);n=e-(i=Math.floor(e/a))*a;for(var l=0;l<i;l++)s+=t+", ";return(s+n+", "+(e+2)).split(",").join("px,")+"px"}}]),t}();window.LazyLinePainter=o;var l=o;e.default=l,t.exports=e.default}])});
//# sourceMappingURL=lazy-line-painter-1.9.6.min.js.map



 
    <!DOCTYPE html>
      <!--[if lt IE 7]>      <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
      <!--[if IE 7]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
      <!--[if IE 8]>         <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
      <!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
      <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <title>Lazy Line Painter</title>
        <meta name="description" content="A modern JS library for SVG path animation">

           
        <!-- Include lazylinepainter -->
        <script src="lazy-line-painter-1.9.6.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">

          (function(){ 

            document.onreadystatechange = () => {

              if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
                        
                let el = document.querySelector('#App_Wolfgang');
                let myAnimation = new LazyLinePainter(el, {"ease":"easeLinear","strokeWidth":0.8,"strokeOpacity":1,"strokeColor":"#222F3D","strokeCap":"square","reverse":true}); 
                myAnimation.paint(); 
              }
            }

          })();

        </script>
      </head>

      <body>
        <svg version="1.1" id="App_Wolfgang" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 236.5 218" style="enable-background:new 0 0 236.5 218;" xml:space="preserve" data-llp-composed="true" class="lazy-line-painter">
<style type="text/css">
    .st0{fill:none;stroke:#1C1C1C;stroke-width:0.25;stroke-linecap:round;stroke-linejoin:round;stroke-miterlimit:10;}
</style>
<g id="Calque_1_00000000201492983179209440000017607601844439870877_">
    <path class="st0" d="M207.2,175.7" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-0" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M116.9,54.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-1" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M112.4,56" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-2" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M71.7,156.9c-0.4,7-3.4,14-1,20.9c0.9,4.4,6,8.4,7.1,1.6c1.4-16.1-6.1-31.1-12.7-45.3&#10;&#9;&#9;c-13.9-29.3-25.5-59.5-38.7-89c-0.9-3.9-7.9-11.9-2.8-15c9.4-4.3,20.3-3.1,30.3-5c7-0.9,18.4-2.5,25.3-3.3c1.5-0.1,4.6-0.9,5.3,0.8&#10;&#9;&#9;c0,0.1-0.1,0.2,0,0.2c0,0,0.4,0.9,0.4,0.9c16.2,40,38.8,86.7,54.2,127.2c-1.3,1.9-5.2,2-7.3,2.6c-3.2,0.7-6.5,1.5-9.7,2.4&#10;&#9;&#9;c-7.5,1.5-16.3,10.6-7.7,16.8c3.4,2.9,9,2.8,11.7-1c5.9-11.4-10.7-12.7-18.3-11.1c-9.9,1.9-23.4,0.6-29.9,9.7" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-3" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M65.2,150.4" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-4" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M53.5,119.2c-13.1,0.5-10.6,16.3,0,9.5c10.4-14.6-12.5-12.8-12.9,1c-4.8,41.3,38.5,49.8,25.2,53&#10;&#9;&#9;c-12.4-3.7-18.7-21-7.8-29.8c9-7.2,12.5,3.5,5.2,9.2" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-5" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M59.1,127.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-6" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M26.8,102.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-7" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M82.4,11c-3-12.2-37.3-4-47.9-4.2C24.8,8.2,1.7,5.2,7.9,21.2c6.1,21.4,13.4,42.7,23.2,62.6&#10;&#9;&#9;c1.4,1.1,2.2-1.6,2.1-2.7c-0.5-6.8-7.3-13.6-14.4-11.9c-12.7,6.6,8.8,12.6,11.7,18c1.6,3.5-2.7,6.4-3.8,8.9&#10;&#9;&#9;c-3.3,7,6.5,18.3,13.1,18.3c3.8-2.5-3.9-4,3.2-15.7c2.3-10.1-12.2-8.2-14.3-0.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-8" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M82.2,14.1c0.6,1.9,0.6,2.1,1,4.1c0-0.1,3.5,1.3,2.7,0.4C81.8,6.5,77.1,5,65,6.5c-9.5,1.7-23.6-0.3-28.1,10.3&#10;&#9;&#9;c7.3-0.6,18.4-0.8,24.7-3.4c-6-0.1-15.9,2.1-22.6,2c5.2-8,17.6-5.9,26-7.6C71.6,7.4,80.1,6,82.2,14.1" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-9" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M32.2,82.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-10" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M31.6,83.3" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-11" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M31.7,83.2" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-12" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M30.9,82.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-13" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M24.6,71.9" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-14" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M29.7,104.3c-5.8-7.4,8.5-13.5,1.3-20.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-15" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M56.2,122.9c3.9,6.6-9.1,12.6-5.3,25.8c0,1.2,0.1,2.6-0.5,3.7c-5.6-5.3-12-11.8-12.3-19.9c0-3,1.3-6.1,0.7-9.2&#10;&#9;&#9;c-0.8-7.1-9.5-9.8-10.5-16.4" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-16" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M50.1,122.7" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-17" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M52.6,126.2" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-18" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M47.6,121.8" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-19" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M62.5,172.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-20" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M66.3,174.8" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-21" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M69.7,177.4" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-22" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M70.4,178.7" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-23" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M49.5,164.1" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-24" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M62.8,147.3" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-25" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M65.5,147.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-26" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M68.1,148.9" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-27" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M72.4,150.5c-7.1-9.6-19.4,3.3-16.2,12.1c4.3,9.8,16.1-1.9,14.3-8.8" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-28" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M74.8,158.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-29" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M73.5,165.2" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-30" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M74.5,178.9" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-31" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M110.2,165.3c3.1-0.2,16.1-1,11,4.8c-4.2,1.8-8.7-4.2-3.8-6.7c7-5.7,17.3-3.6,24.5-8.9&#10;&#9;&#9;c3.2-3.4,0.7-8.2-0.9-11.7c-8-19.8-47.5-102.6-53.3-120.9c-1-6.7-13-2.4-17.4-2.4c-3,0.4-18.4,2.5-21.1,2.9&#10;&#9;&#9;C39.6,24.6,15,21,18.9,36.7C36,77.7,54.8,115.6,71.7,156.9" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-32" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M231.9,204c-20.5-29.7-51.1-55.8-70.2-86.2c-9.9-15.5-19.3-31.6-27.9-48C131.4,59.6,126,59,120,52.4&#10;&#9;&#9;c-2.6-5.3-9.1-16.6-13.6-10.6c-4.1,5.5,2.8,14.1,9.9,17.3c3.1-18.2-14.5-28.6-16.4-10.4c12.5,34.7,30.9,67.1,45,101.2&#10;&#9;&#9;c7.4,17.6,9.9,17.7-9.9,24.2c-16,3.2-32,12.8-48.3,12.1c-4.6-2.7-7.2-9.9-4.2-14.5c7.7-5.6,18.6-5.1,27.7-6.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-33" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M160.5,215.8c-1.5-1.3-2.8-2.9-3.9-4.6c-4.3-3.3-10-5.2-14.9-7.5c-10.8-3-21.6-10-32.9-9.7&#10;&#9;&#9;c0.3,4.1,5.8,6.1,9.2,7.6c8.9,3.9,18.7,1.5,27.5-1.4c15.2-3.4,13.8-18.8,21.7-29.9c23.7-27.3,49.3,19.5,64.7,33.7" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-34" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M153.5,210.8" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-35" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M149.8,208.9" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-36" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M142.4,205.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-37" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M138,204" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-38" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M133.4,202.3" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-39" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M134.8,201.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-40" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M100.8,56.2 M103.8,54.8 M105.9,59.2 M108.2,63.9 M113.6,76.2 M114.9,79.5 M111.3,80.9 M118.5,97.4&#10;&#9;&#9; M116.7,160.7 M140.4,153.1 M141.4,149.8 M121.4,103.8 M125,102 M130.2,112.7 M141.4,136.9 M146.7,149.2 M149.2,155.4 M150.2,157.6&#10;&#9;&#9; M151.7,161.5 M152.5,164.5 M152.1,167.5 M150.2,169.8 M148.8,170.7 M147.5,171.4 M135.5,176.1 M129.1,177.9 M123,179.6&#10;&#9;&#9; M114.7,182.3 M110.6,183.6 M98.2,187.2 M91.8,188.5 M85.7,188 M81.3,183.8 M79.3,177.9 M80.1,171.8 M80.5,171.1 M84.8,167.8&#10;&#9;&#9; M110,163.3 M113.2,163.1 M125.1,167.6 M123.6,164.6 M120.8,162.9 M114.6,162.4 M81,169.4 M77,176.8 M106.4,41.8&#10;&#9;&#9;c-10,6.3,2,17.7,4.4,25.9c10.4,27.6,25.2,52.3,36.3,79.4c1.8,4.7,4.5,10.3,6.2,15c3.6,11.7-16.5,14-24.1,16.8&#10;&#9;&#9;c-12.5,3.2-24.6,8.6-37.7,10.5c-8.2,1.9-12.5-7-13.5-13.8 M103.4,43.3 M102.1,45.8 M101.8,48.5 M102.8,52.5 M197.9,165.2" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-41" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M111.7,125.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-42" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M115.3,129.3" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-43" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M116.1,125.9" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-44" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M71.6,62.3" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-45" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M115.2,136.3c-5,3.4-32.7-4.6-35.4-9.8c-2.7-8,22.6,0.3,25.8,2.2c4.9,2.4,8.7,6.6,12.3,10.5&#10;&#9;&#9;c-6.8-28.1-22.7-53-40.7-75.3" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-46" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M80.5,136.9c1.3,0,16.9,0.2,18,0.8c4.6,6.6,12.6,5.1,18.8,1.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-47" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M63.9,53" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-48" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M65.6,56.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-49" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M79.5,90.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-50" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M65.5,58c-1.1-1.7,2.6,7.7,2.9,8.5c4.3,15.8,8.6,32.1,8.7,48.6c-0.3,1,1.2,1.3,1.8,1.8&#10;&#9;&#9;c5.7,4,12.1,7.2,17.5,11.6l0,0" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-51" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M98.9,125.5c0,0.1,0,0.1,0,0.2l0,0C98.9,125.6,98.9,125.5,98.9,125.5L98.9,125.5c-11-23.9-22.7-49.1-33.3-73.2&#10;&#9;&#9;l-2.1,1.4c6.9,13.4,11.7,28,17.7,41.8c4.6,10.7,10.1,22.5,15.1,33" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-52" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M100.7,125.8" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-53" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M87.6,127.8c5.6,1.9,10.8,5.4,16.6,6.4c4.4,0.2,1.6-4.9-0.4-6.3" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-54" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M86.2,127.1" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-55" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M84.7,126.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-56" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M80.3,125.9" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-57" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M79.2,125.8" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-58" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M79.4,129" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-59" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M86.2,135.1" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-60" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M94.1,135.6" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-61" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M111.7,126.5" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-62" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M90.6,85.8" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-63" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
    <path class="st0" d="M70.5,60.3c-3.1-2.4,9.1,12.4,10.3,13.9c9.3,13.8,15.4,30.4,17.3,46.9c7.7-0.4,14.2,5.2,18.3,11.2l0,0&#10;&#9;&#9;c1.3-9.8,1.5-20-3.2-29C103.4,85.2,89.4,69.4,70.5,60.3" data-llp-id="App_Wolfgang-64" data-llp-duration="2510" data-llp-delay="0" fill-opacity="0" style=""/>
</g>
</svg>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: can't see any vuejs in your code at all

Comment: The code I edited is the "index.html" file (with a call to minified file) that I want to adapt to my vuejs code,  I just want to adapt it as a vue component for exemple